# Inject Ethereum Provider EIP-1193 into my wallet

Tags: wallets, eip

I'm trying to implement injected wallet like Metamask and Trust Wallet where my wallet plugin pops up when clicking on Injected which I implemented using Wagmi. I think the wallets are detected through window.ethereum after reading a few documentations but I still wasn't sure what should I do. Would love to have some examples or documents to implement it in the simplest way

Answer (score 1):

here is a link to all the docs about connectors, hooks, and configuration:
https://wagmi.sh/react/getting-started

So assuming you have npm or yarn installed wagmi to your react project, you have to then initialize it in your index.js or index.jsx file like so:

```
import { WagmiConfig, createClient, configureChains, chain } from "wagmi";

import { infuraProvider } from "wagmi/providers/infura";
import { InjectedConnector } from "wagmi/connectors/injected";
import { MetaMaskConnector } from "wagmi/connectors/metaMask";
import { WalletConnectConnector } from "wagmi/connectors/walletConnect";

// this is how you configure providers and chains you would like to use

const { chains, provider, webSocketProvider } = configureChains(
  [mainnet],
  // if you don't have alchemy or infura you can use public provider
  [publicProvider()],
  [infuraProvider({ apiKey: "replace with infura api key" })]
);

// configure connectors

const client = createClient({
  connectors: [
    new InjectedConnector({
      options: {
        name: "CONNECTOR NAME",
        getProvider: () =>
          typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.ethereum : undefined,
      },
    }),
    new MetaMaskConnector({ chains }),
    new WalletConnectConnector({
      options: {
        chains,
        qrcode: true,
        rpc: {
          1: "replace with infura, alchemy, or public rpc url",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  autoConnect: true,
  chains,
  provider,
  webSocketProvider,
});

// then wrap your App component or routes in the WagmiConfig 
// to use provided hooks and state throughout your app

function App() {
  return (
    <WagmiConfig client={client}>
      <App />
    </WagmiConfig>
  )
}
```

after you have the client configured you can create a separate page or component for the login. Here is an example from the docs on how to set that up:

```
import { useAccount, useConnect } from "wagmi";

function ConnectPage() {
  const { connector: activeConnector, isConnected } = useAccount();
  const { connect, connectors, error, isLoading, pendingConnector } =
    useConnect();

  return (
    <>
      {isConnected && <div>Connected to {activeConnector.name}</div>}

      // this will loop through all the connectors you 
      // peviously set up in config and create connect buttons for each.

      {connectors.map((connector) => (
        <button
          disabled={!connector.ready}
          key={connector.id}
          onClick={() => connect({ connector })}
        >
          {connector.name}
          {isLoading &&
            pendingConnector?.id === connector.id &&
            " (connecting)"}
        </button>
      ))}
      {error && <div>{error.message}</div>}
    </>
  );
}
```